# Unable to install Apache OpenOffice 4.1 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: software-installation

I am using Edubuntu OS and upgraded it to Ubuntu 14.04. But, I am not able to install Apache OpenOffice 4.1. It gives error, 'bad package'. Whereas, I could install it on Windows within 50 minutes and also using it. Open source platform purpose is not solved unless open software run properly on free OS also.

Answer (score 15):

Follow these steps to install OpenOffice 4.1 onto Ubuntu 14.04.  Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge libreoffice* #if installed and you want to remove it.
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Download OpenOffice

For 32 bit

```
wget http://sourceforge.net/projects/openofficeorg.mirror/files/4.1.0/binaries/en-US/Apache_OpenOffice_4.1.0_Linux_x86_install-deb_en-US.tar.gz
```

For 64 bit

```
wget http://sourceforge.net/projects/openofficeorg.mirror/files/4.1.0/binaries/en-US/Apache_OpenOffice_4.1.0_Linux_x86-64_install-deb_en-US.tar.gz
```

Extract the file

```
tar -xvfz Apache_OpenOffice_4.1.0_Linux_x86_install-deb_en-US.tar.gz (for 32bit)

tar -xvfz Apache_OpenOffice_4.1.0_Linux_x86-64_install-deb_en-US.tar.gz (for 64bit)

cd en-US/DEBS/
sudo dpkg -i *.deb 
cd desktop-integration
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

make sure that you have the space between the command dpkg and the -i

For Libreoffice installation do the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/libreoffice-4-3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libreoffice
```

Or you can download the .deb file from Libreoffice, and install it that way.

**Note**: Both Libreoffice and Open Office can co-exist on the same machine.

Comment: Is it necessary to remove libreoffice or could those two coexist on the same machine?

Comment: Both can co-exist on the same machine.

Comment: Your answer would be better if you explain how to make coexist libreoffice and apache openoffice.

Comment: `tar: z: Cannot open: No such file or directory` so the command need to change so that `f` stays in the end: `tar -xvzf Apache_OpenOffice_4.1.0_Linux_x86-64_install-deb_en-US.tar.gz `

Comment: Indeed without removing libre-office first, it fails to install open office

Comment: Looks to me like libre-office is much easier to hang, open office more robust and beautiful. At least the spreadsheet part.

Comment: for unziping use xzf instead of -xvfz